# Trying to parse xml from url store to string so I can use in another spot to output to irc

Tags: python, xml, irc

The following is the xml from remote URL

```
<SHOUTCASTSERVER>
<CURRENTLISTENERS>0</CURRENTLISTENERS>
<PEAKLISTENERS>0</PEAKLISTENERS>
<MAXLISTENERS>100</MAXLISTENERS>
<UNIQUELISTENERS>0</UNIQUELISTENERS>
<AVERAGETIME>0</AVERAGETIME>
<SERVERGENRE>variety</SERVERGENRE>
<SERVERGENRE2/>
<SERVERGENRE3/>
<SERVERGENRE4/>
<SERVERGENRE5/>
<SERVERURL>http://localhost/</SERVERURL>
<SERVERTITLE>Wicked Radio WIKD/WPOS</SERVERTITLE>
<SONGTITLE>Unknown - Haxor Radio Show 08</SONGTITLE>
<STREAMHITS>0</STREAMHITS>
<STREAMSTATUS>1</STREAMSTATUS>
<BACKUPSTATUS>0</BACKUPSTATUS>
<STREAMLISTED>0</STREAMLISTED>
<STREAMLISTEDERROR>200</STREAMLISTEDERROR>
<STREAMPATH>/stream</STREAMPATH>
<STREAMUPTIME>448632</STREAMUPTIME>
<BITRATE>128</BITRATE>
<CONTENT>audio/mpeg</CONTENT>
<VERSION>2.4.7.256 (posix(linux x64))</VERSION>
</SHOUTCASTSERVER>
```

All I am trying to do is store the contents of the element `<SONGTITLE>` store it so I can post to IRC using a bot that I have.

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

url = "http://142.4.217.133:9203/stats?sid=1&mode=viewxml&page=0"
fp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
doc = etree.parse(fp)
fp.close()

for record in doc.xpath('//SONGTITLE'):
    for x in record.xpath("./subfield/text()"):
        print "\t", x
```

That is what I have so far; not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am quite new to python but the IRC bot works and does some other utility type things I just want to add this as a feature to it.

Comment: Can you explain what is currently not working out? What errors are you getting. What is happening that you don't expect?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include `./subfield/`:

```
for x in record.xpath("text()"):
```

**Output:**

```
Unknown - Haxor Radio Show 08
```